# How to execute a html embedded ruby code on local machine

Tags: html, ruby, embedded-ruby

I am pretty much new to ruby. How can we run a html embedded ruby code on our local machine.? I have ruby 1.8 installed on my machine. Do I need to install rails too for running that html with ruby code ? I got stucked ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To evaluate the Ruby code manually you can use the `erb` command.

Given a `index.html.rhtml` file with the following content:

```
<html><body>Hello <%= "from Ruby" %></body></html>
```

Running:

```
$ erb index.html.rhtml > index.html
```

Results in a `index.html` file with:

```
<html><body>Hello from Ruby</body></html>
```

This file can be viewed in a browser.

Another option is to use a *web server* to convert and serve the files. Here's a one liner starting [WebBrick](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html) on port 3000 (assuming a `index.html.rhtml` file in the current directory):

```
$ ruby -rwebrick -e "WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:DocumentRoot => '.', :Port => 3000).start"
```

Pointing your browser to `http://localhost:3000/index.html.rhtml` should show the page.

Comment: @stefan.thnku it works.I hav a doubt in code that I have writtn, if u dont mind can u let me knw where I might hav gone wrong?
What I am doing is trying to get the array of Strings into option list,but m not gettin the list in the dropdown.
`<html>
<select id = 'status_update' style  = 'width:225px; font-size: 11.4px;'>
<%=
array = ["Submitted", "Replied", "Answered", "Assigned", "Started", "Closed", "Canceled"]
 status = '';
 for index in 0 .. (array.size-1)
   status << "<option value = '#{puts (eval(array[index].inspect))}'>'#{(array[index].inspect)}'</option>"
 end
%>
</select> </html>`

Comment: @Rak please post a separate question

Comment: yeah i have just created a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. Try this. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/ruby-hello-world-example-how-to-write-and-execute-ruby-program-on-unix-os/

Comment: @Nishan. Thank you, but I am aware of this execution of a ruby code through terminal. But my case is like, executing a html page with an embedded ruby code. I put some ruby code in an html and trying to see my output when I run that html page on a browser.